# How to globally set Ionic components buttons translation?

Tags: ionic-framework

is there a way to globally configure ionic components buttons text?

I need to translate for example Input Properties like:
- cancelText, okText from [Select](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/) component
- cancelText, doneText from [DateTime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/) component

Is there a similar way to set those strings in [Config](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/)? Like `backButtonText`:

```
this.config.set('backButtonText', this.translate.instant("BACK"))
```

**I would like to do something like:**

```
this.config.set('cancelText', this.translate.instant("CANCEL"));
this.config.set('doneText',   this.translate.instant("DONE"));
this.config.set('okText',   this.translate.instant("OK"));
```

**Instead of doing this for each component template:**

```
<ion-select [cancelText]="translate.instant('CANCEL')" [okText]="translate.instant('OK')"></ion-select>
<ion-datetime [cancelText]="translate.instant('CANCEL')" [doneText]="translate.instant('DONE')"></ion-datetime>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use $translateProvider.  https://angular-translate.github.io/   with this you can put all your translations in a single file and use them in your app.

Comment: I've already set up my translations, that's not my problem. I want to translate ionic components buttons once for all, not for every component in the template. backButtonText is supported by Config, the other strings not.

Comment: @FabianoTavallini Did you manage to do this?

Comment: No @Thomas i ended up setting on each component to finish my work